# \glossaries Package doesn't Work

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to get the \glossaries package to work but no luck. This MWE compiles but does not display a glossary.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{12345}
{
name=12345,
description={My favorite numbers}
}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[20]
\clearpage
\printglossary[title=Special Terms, toctitle=List of terms]
\end{document}
```

Tried to follow the instructions here: [Formatting for glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197222/formatting-for-glossaries) but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At first you need to use the term, e.g. with \gls.

Comment: Also I think you have to change `\makeglossaries` to `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printglossary` to `\printnoidxglossary`. You are trying to use an option without indices. It should work after changes, although that is not a recommended option (see _Indexing Options_ in the [dcumentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) for more info).